# Java 1.8, tomcat 8.5, Jersey 2 - Can't make it work

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I went over everything, even made some changes, fixed some problems but still the server sends back 404 even though tomcat itself is up and running. Following is what I did:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.resty</groupId>
    <artifactId>resty</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>resty</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>resty</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.resty</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resty/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Resty.java

```
package com.resty;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/resty")
public class Resty {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/example")
    public String getExample() {
        return "{\"result\":\"blah\"}";
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something but I just can't figure out what it is. When run as - running on server, eclipse opens this url: http://localhost:9090/Resty/ but I see 404. I tried adding more resty/ to the url and also /example (see code above) but all gives 404.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe the url is case sensitive, did you look in tomcats webapps dir to see what name it is deployed as?

Comment: Do you declare `application` on `web.xml`?
Also, check from Tomcat monitor page that application started or fail?

Comment: I lowercased all resty in the code and tried again, added resty/ to the url one after the other but all are 404. removing all resty/ from the url shows that tomcat is alive. What should be the url from the above configuration? Under tomcat I see folders called "Resty"

Comment: @ManhLe I didn't. What it should be and where? tomcat console shows it is started. localhost:9090 shows tomcat welcome page

Comment: See section `4.7.2.3` in https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#d0e3683

Comment: @ManhLe added the instructed servlet, called it resty as well (to make sure) and tried the url up to http://localhost:9090/resty/resty/resty/example (with and without example in the end) but no luck

Comment: Why too much `resty`s on your url? I think there are 2 `resty`s on url.

Comment: I meant that I tried localhost:9090/resty and localhost:9090/resty/resty/ and localhost:9090/resty/resty/resty but nothing worked. Also notice there is @Path("/example") on the function itself

Answer (score 1):

you are using `<url-pattern>/resty/*</url-pattern>` in `web.xml` and using `@Path("/resty")` in class for class mapping, and use url `http://localhost:9090/Resty/` that is wrong. you need to use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. and url will be `http://localhost:9090/resty/`

you can also use anything into `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` which you want but you need to use this pattern before controller path in url.

Comment: I lowercased all "resty" and re-run it, I changed url-pattern to /* but to no avail. Still 404.